# When to use a Binary Heap based Priority Queue vs a Linked List based Priority Queue?

Tags: linked-list, queue, heap, priority-queue

You can implement a Priority Queue using Binary Heaps or using Linked Lists. I believe the Linked List implementation allows for O(n) insertions and O(1) removals, whereas the Binary Heap implementation allows for O(log n) insertions and O(log n) removals.

The only advantage of the Linked List implementation (that I can tell) is that you can remove items from the Priority Queue quickly (in constant time). However, in order to remove items, you must first add items, meaning that we need to consider the time to add as well.

Therefore, would that not mean that the Binary Heap implementation is **ALWAYS** better than the Linked List implementation, since O(n + 1) is slower than O(log n + log n)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you have everything organized by priority up front and you don't have many/any elements to add on the middle of the linked structure, then you can build the linked list up front and you're done, but then you don't need/aren't really using a priority queue, you're just using a standard linked list with interior access. So if you're writing a general priority queue class, I can't think of why you'd ever implement it with a queue/LL that has O(n) add or change priority methods. Can you cite your use case and sources here for the "linked priority queue"?

Comment: In order to remove arbitrary elements you have to find them first, which makes removal O(n) for both binary heaps and linked lists.

Comment: Linked lists also lose on storage requirements, since they must contain both the data and the node pointers.  Binary heaps are usually implemented with arrays where the reference information is an offset corresponding to the index rather than an actual pointer requiring storage.